# how to pick specific words from script and create a new one with them withouth spaces

Tags: shell

I'm want to read a string from file
this string is for example

```
&0001 = 1234 5678 9abc
```

now I want to take this string and build another string from it which is

```
123456789abc
```

I succeeded to read the the string from the end of the file by

```
read_addr="`awk "END {print}" file.txt`"
echo ${read_addr}
```

how should I continue to create the string 123456789abc out of the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this instead:

```
tail -n 1 file.txt | sed 's/ //g' | sed 's/.*=//'
```

The `tail -n 1` gives you the last line of the file and the `sed 's/ //g'` removes the spaces.

Comment: I also want to remove the &0001 =

Comment: I've added an extra sed for that part :)

Answer (score 1):

you can just change your awk line a little bit:

```
awk -F= 'END{gsub(/ /,"",$2);print $2}' file.txt
```

this awk line will do the simple task with single process.